# react-native-maps Polyline Traffic Color

Tags: google-maps, react-native, maps, polyline, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps and polyline to draw a route on the map (I am using multiple waypoints).  I want to be able to color the Polyline based on the traffic (red for heavy traffic, yellow for moderate, etc) similar to the way Google Maps does it normally.

As I am thinking of multiple ways and looking online, I've seen that you can use the Embed API, however that has to be wrapped in an iframe (not what I'm looking for).  It seems the coordinates used to map the Polyline doesn't correspond to the responses received from the Routes API either (and hence I can't really use the time and distance received from there to calculate whether it is in traffic and plot the polyline).

I'd like to ask everyone if there are any specific methods or ideas to accomplish this?

Comment: Note: you shouldn't try to recreate exact features of Google Maps in your app as it violates TOS. 
Are you able to share what you've tried so far, maybe in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q4qymyp2l6)? If you just want to create multiple polylines and color them based on something like `duration_in_traffic` you can try to create an array of polylines and color them separately like [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287136/adding-multiple-polylines-on-react-native-map-with-google-api-coordinates)

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of that as well.  Unfortunately that would also require multiple API calls in one go in order to determine each sections `duration_in_traffic` and I was hoping to avoid that.  I don't think I'd be able to recreate the preciseness that Google map has, but I was hoping I'd be able to show approximately where traffic was occurring to an app user in order for them to be able to see the location of traffic.

Do you mind sharing where it states that in the TOS?  I took a look at it and wasn't able to find anything in the TOS.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I haven't tried anything in particular so far either.  I've been brainstorming ideas on how to tackle this problem, and the only answer I've been able to come up with is to draw multiple polylines into the map with each section having an API call get the `duration_in_traffic` and using that to determine how traffic that section is and set a polyline color based on it.  Using Embed API isn't an option either.